# Replacing console aplication interface with an MFC

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, mfc

I have a phone-book program written in C++, that uses the MVC model, now what I want is to replace the View component, that's basically the console window, with an MFC. How would I do that?

Comment: This question seems overly broad. Have you ever done (GUI) programming? Have you thought of any ideas already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a schematic representation of **MVC**. `View` component is lossely coupled from the `Model` and the `Controller` and that is the whole point behind MVC design pattern. Without changing the external interfaces of View, you should be easily able to replace internal implementation by MFC. And that is what you should do.
The question is very broad to answer anything more in detail, If you can post a sample code then probably we can help you better.

[image: Model View Controller]